# when i do command prompt for the django version it doesnt come up even though its successful on pycharm help please

Tags: python, django, pycharm, command-prompt

when i do command prompt on windows for the django version it doesn't come up even though its successful installed on pycharm help please.
i am new to python as well.
when i go on to command prompt on windows to check django version after adding `python -m django --version`
i get this result:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: No
> module named django

i am using pycharm as IDE and it seems when i did install django on pycharm it was successful should i worry about the django version coming up on command prompt or not.

I am using windows 10 to do my coding for Uni so its not on any other OS  :)

Comment: You probably have to set virtualenv and use Django that is installed in this virtual python environment.

Comment: @AlexBaranowski i am not using any virtual environment at all its straight from my windows 10 OS.

Comment: @Lost_Angel the virtual environment said above is not a virtual machine as you think think it is. A virtual environment is also something that is used in python to keep a projects packages separate from other project's packages. Mostly pycharm automatically set's up a virtual environment for your projects if you make them through it. see [Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ok thank you! ill go have a look :)

Comment: As @AbdulAzizBarkat mentioned, PyCharm creates virtual environments automatically. In PyCharm, open the terminal using `Alt-F12`, then enter your command `python -m django --version`.

Answer (score 0):

try this command after reopening your cmd
django-admin --version